# Webstorm JSX emmet expansion

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsx, emmet, jetbrains-ide

When using Webstorm in context of javascript, there is a "func" live template, which allows me to write `fun|`, press `Tab` and expand `fun` to

```
function | () {

}
```

with placeholders for `function name`, `arguments` and `body`.

But in context of JSX Harmony pressing `Tab` after you've input some text in function name expands Emmet tag instead of going to `arguments` placeholder:

```
function <someFunction>|</someFunction> () {

}
```

Is there a way to disable emmet expansion while in a live template or snippet?

Comment: Try `Enter` instead of `Tab` (to navigate to the next placeholder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow [IDEABKL-6454](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6454) for updates. As a workaround please do not use `Tab` to jump to next field when expanding live templates - `Enter` will stop editing current value and move cursor to next one. Or, try changing Emmet expanding shortcut